# Adding a whiteboard in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, whiteboard

I am working on a website which needs a whiteboard functionality on a page where teacher will teach the student using whiteboard and text chat. For every student that opens the page, a new whiteboard and session should be started. The site is built on WordPress. I see whiteboard solutions are there in Node.js but no solution in WordPress. Can I embed Node.js whiteboard within WordPress? Is there any other solution?

Comment: At your rep you should know this is far too broad.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Hi. Whats the best way to ask such a question?